# Dealing with recurrent sequences

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, tikzmath

I have the following code to calculate the approximations for arctan(1) recursively:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newcommand{\seriefinal}[1]{
  \tikzmath{
  function Impressao(\r){print{$\fpeval{round(\r,6)}$};};
    function serieF(\n) {
      real \s; real \a; real \e;
      \s = 0;
       for \i in {1,...,\n}{
         if isodd(\i+1) == 1 then {
         \s = \s - 1/(2*\i-1); % Computa valor de séries
         };
         if isodd(\i+1) == 0 then {
         \s = \s + 1/(2*\i-1); % Computa valor de séries
         };
         \e = abs(1/(2*\i-1));
       };
      return \s;
    };
    int #1;
     Impressao(serieF(#1));
  }
}

\begin{document}

The approximation for atan(1) is equal to:\seriefinal{10} with an error less than:

\end{document}
```

The value for serie with 10 terms is calculatet by \seriefinal{10}. Furthermore, I would like to provide the error with this approximation, calculated by \e = abs(1/(2*\i-1)). The first question is:

1. I don't know how can I return two values for function "serieF", i.e., I would like to obtain the sum \s and error \e (two outputs for this function).
2. I would like to plot the sequence of points (\i,serieF(\i)) for i=1,2,...,100, for example. How can I do this?
   Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I interpret the question as the desire to avoid doing the recursion twice. That is, I do not touch the fact that you build in some print in the function (I think you may not want to do that) nor using `xfp`, the rounding could also done with pgf.

The point is that you can use arrays. So the function now returns a tuple of `value` and `error`. You can then access the error via a macro.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\newcommand{\seriefinal}[1]{%
  \tikzmath{
  function Impressao(\r){print{$\fpeval{round(\r,6)}$};};
  function serieF(\n) {
      real \s; real \a; real \e;
      \s = 0;
      \e = 0;
       for \i in {1,...,\n}{
         if isodd(\i+1) == 1 then {
         \s = \s - 1/(2*\i-1); % 
         };
         if isodd(\i+1) == 0 then {
         \s = \s + 1/(2*\i-1); % 
         };
         \e = abs(1/(2*\i-1));
       };
      return {\s,\e};
    };
    int #1;
    \s = {serieF(#1)}[0];
    \e = {serieF(#1)}[1];
    \errorval{#1}=\e;
    return Impressao(\s);
  }%
}

\begin{document}

The approximation for $\operatorname{atan}(1)$ is equal to \seriefinal{10} 
with an error less than $\errorval{10}$. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can employ LuaLaTeX to compile your document, you could make use of Lua's library of math functions, including `math.atan` and `math.pi`. No need for series approximations.

In the following code, `\luaexec` rather than `\directlua` is used, as `\luaexec` allows passing a `%` symbol from the TeX side to the Lua side as `\%`. (`\directlua` does not offer this facility.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for "\luaexec" macro
\begin{document}
$\arctan(1)\approx \luaexec{tex.sprint(string.format("\%.10f",math.atan(1)))}$.

Also, $\pi/4\approx\luaexec{tex.sprint(string.format("\%.10f",math.pi/4))}$.
\end{document}
```